# Well attended: What question has the most views?

Tags: support, views

What SE question has the most views, and where could I find this information?

Comment: Probably the data explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it quite easily (per site) with a simple [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/507504/642211/):

```sql
SELECT TOP 10
  id AS [Post Link],
  ViewCount  
  FROM posts ORDER BY viewcount DESC
```

[git - How do you undo the last commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358) is the most viewed Stack Overflow question with over 3 million views.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/507508/642216/) is another query which returns the top 10 viewed queries from *each* Stack Exchange site, which proves the question above is indeed the most popular one over *all* Stack Exchange site. Further down the list it gives some mildly surprising results (at least in my opinion).

```sql
-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #questions ( site nvarchar(250), id int, title nvarchar(250), viewcount int);
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
    insert into #questions 
    select top 10 '''+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +''', id, title, viewcount
      from posts
      where posttypeid = 1
      order by viewcount desc';
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select * from #questions order by viewcount desc
```